# What is the bitrate of itunes streaming

Tags: itunes, music, streaming, bitrate

I've been using itunes streaming (in part cause its easy) to access my music collection between two windows PCs. I'm half certain it sounds kinda 'flat' so i'm wondering, what bitrate it uses, and format - it sounds fine off a PMP, and even better on a PC, so i assume i can tell the difference.